# Android: Custom Spinner xml

Tags: android, xml, spinner, android-spinner, android-drawable

I'm New to Android and want to customize the spinner in an app I'm making.
This is what I want my spinners to look like http://prntscr.com/bk4pbt. I tried setting the background of the spinner to an image of the shape but it not looking how i want it to be.

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewStore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="Store:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/text" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/store_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/store_prompt" />
```

Comment: What is the drawable you used for the Spinner?

Comment: it was a rounded rectangle I made in photoshop

Comment: Was it a 9-patch drawable?

Comment: no it wasn't @cricket_007